# How to use multiple array in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [emp_name] => 
            [emp_title] => Senior Developer
            [emp_master_id] => 0
            [emp_designation] => TL
            [emp_skills] => PHP, MySQL
            [emp_experience] => 4-5
            [emp_location] => Chennai
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [emp_name] => 
            [emp_title] => Web Developer
            [emp_master_id] => 0
            [emp_designation] => Senior Developer
            [emp_skills] => 10Base-T Switching, PHP
            [emp_experience] => 4-5
            [emp_location] => Chennai
        )

)
```

I want Insert the array In Db by using Foreach.. Any Suggestions

Comment: You can use array_keys and array_values functions to do that

Comment: you don't necessarilly need a `foreach` here. `array_column` `array_values` should help

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide some more information regarding the question so that it will be easier to understand for other users . You can check [How to ask a complete question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why do incomplete questions like this one upvoted?

Comment: can anyone provide in foreach statement for this one.. Array_keys or Values not used it

Answer (score 1):

let say your array name is $data

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){
  $sql="Insert into table_name (empname,..... )values('".$value['empname']."',....);";

  $result=$conn->query($sql);

}
```

This should do the work, Assuming that you have connection variable something like

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Give the column name **as in your table** in the **sql query**.

**EDIT**
The secure way of doing it

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name(emp_name, title, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ..)");//No of question marks are equal to columns you have mentioed
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $empName, $title, ...);
//   i - integer
//   d - double
//   s - string
//   b - BLOB


// set parameters and execute
$empName= $value['empname'];
$title= $value['title'];
//continue to do it for all...

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

}
$conn->close();
```

**NOTE:** You can use function also if you know how to do it, less code inside the foreach
 
Happy coding :)

Comment: please don't encourage SQL string concatenation, you're effectively suggesting that people write code which is vulnerable to SQL Injection. An example using parameterised queries would be much better.

Comment: Ya i understand, but it's a quick way to do. I  If he consider about the security he need learn it. I just show him the way how it can be achieved, i don't want make it complex for him to understand. is it wrong @ADyson ?

Comment: Many people don't even know about the security implications. It doesn't take much longer to write a more correct example, IMO. Or, you could ignore the DB part of it (and leave that to the user), because really the question is about iterating over the array.

Comment: that's more like it. Although shouldn't you assign values to $empName and $title _before_ you bind them? And you don't want to be closing the connection inside the foreach, I don't think - very inefficient to close/re-open for each query, and also you haven't opened it in the loop, so the second iteration will fail due to closed connection..

Comment: before the execution it's possible to assign i guess.. i will take the connection close outside the loop.

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach($arr as $v){
    $sql = ') VALUES (';
    foreach($v as $k => $value){
        $sql = ",".$k.$sql.'"'.$value.'",';
    }
    $sql = 'Insert into table_name ('.trim($sql,',').';';
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
}
```

this maybe working.

Comment: please don't encourage SQL string concatenation, you're effectively suggesting that people write code which is vulnerable to SQL Injection. An example using parameterised queries would be much better